# Image doesnt expand entire width on high resolutions

Tags: html, css, grid

I have a website which is using the Golden Grid System. You can see my site here http://syndicatebox.com/helpout/index_fix.html

On low resolutions as in the screenshot below  you can see the top two images span equally and they look correct.

[image]

But below if you look if im over lets say 1980x1080 the top two images retain there size and dont expand the entire width equally.

[image]

I have my code [here](http://syndicatebox.com/helpout/index_fix.html) but I have no idea what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of media queries
Remove following code from you style.css

line no. 373 and 376

```
#twoway .wrapper:first-child {
/* margin-left: 25%; */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 117em)
#twoway .wrapper {
/* width: 25%; */
}
```